# What to do if I need to ask a question which should be discussed, not answered?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to ask a question, which may not have an exact answer, but I need to know other's opinions and their experiences on that issue. Or I have to select between two technologies, languages, IDEs, platforms, etc. and I want to ask a question like:

> Which one is better? X or Y?

I asked this question because in the Stack Overflow ask page, it said not to ask questions which does not have an answer and will be discussed.

Comment: +1 for asking here instead of just posting away

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have over 20 reputation on the Stack Exchange network, you could ask your question in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead of asking it on Stack Overflow. As you have found, these discussion questions aren't constructive for Stack Overflow, but I'm sure people will be more than happy to discuss with you in chat.

Comment: not a bad idea, but I found some similar questions in stackoverflow, which not only were not closed, but also got a lot of votes. I thought maybe I can ask these questions in a way which I don't know.

Comment: @saeed: Did they have the notice _"This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."_?

Comment: @ hammar.- no !

Comment: @saeed: Then please give us links to them so that we can add the notice or take some other appropriate action.

Comment: @ hammar: I do not remember just now, but if I found one, I'll tell you. Thanks anyway